# Open a new tab with a selected word in page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is possible to create an extension for google chrome do: to select a word, click the right button and open a new tab using the word as part of a url?

Example of word: **test**

Go to page: http://www.example.com/**test**

Comment: Note that you ask "is it possible?" The answer is "Yes". But if you're seeking help with _how_ to do it, you should formulate your questions better. Please take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) and [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) in the `background.js`. I've created the code and it works with me.

```
function sendSearch(selectedText) {
 var serviceCall = 'http://www.example.com/' + selectedText;
 chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(
 {
  title: "Find '%s' on example.com!", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: function(info, tab) {
      sendSearch(info.selectionText);
  }
 });
```

Based on the [Best practices when using event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices) @Xan mentioned. You can use [chrome.contextMenus.onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) instead. Like:

```
function sendSearch(selectedText) {
 var serviceCall = 'http://www.example.com/' + selectedText;
 chrome.tabs.create({url: serviceCall});
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(
 {
  title: "Find '%s' on example.com!", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  "id": "ViewSelectedLink"
  });
function contextClicked(info, tab) {
   if (info.menuItemId == "ViewSelectedLink" ) {
       sendSearch(info.selectionText);
   }
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextClicked);
```

Comment: I would recommend moving `onclick` out of the item description into a global event handler. This way it will be compatible with event pages. (See #7 [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#best-practices))